# How to show user input location in Map according to lat, long in android using Google Map v2?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I need to display specific location in Map according to lat,long and also display marker on that particular location.
However, i have displayed whole map but not getting specific location.

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap googleMap;
MarkerOptions markerOptions;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.map);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
    String lat = intent.getStringExtra("lat");
    String lon = intent.getStringExtra("long");
    double Lon = Double.parseDouble(lon);
    double Lat = Double.parseDouble(lat);

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(Lat, Lon))
            .title(title));
      } }
```

Comment: Checkout by printing that whether you get the proper lat long in your intent or not ?

Comment: well, i am getting lat, long and location properly !

Comment: [You are likely to look into this sample code using Google Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code). This sample is needed to you now, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out as below:

> ```
>   private Marker myMarker;
>     myMarker=googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
>         .position(new LatLng(Lat, Lon))
>         .title(title)
>         .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
> ```